# MK -Sending SMS through Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, sms

I'm trying send a personalize SMS and with help in another posts here I constructed this AMPScript:

```
%[ 

VAR @mobile, @date 
SET @mobile = MOBILE_NUMBER 
SET @date = FORMAT(Lookup('DE_NAME','DATE_FIELD','MobilePhone',@mobile),"dd/MM/yyyy")

]%%
Pay you bill at %%=v(@date)=%%,or contact us.
```

However when I have two contacts using the same phone number both SMS shows the same date.

There is another way to get what I need?

Answer (score 0):

The Lookup is finding the first record. You would have to Lookup based one a field that is unique, since you can have duplicate values in the 'MobilePhone' field.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be solved with the newest Marketing Cloud release coming in late June.

According to the [release notes for MobileConnect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_june_2018_sms_contactkey.htm&type=5) there will be an option to use `ContactKey` field as personalization string. Meaning you can finally use unique value to look up some data in your Data Extensions.